# StreamBuilder returns nothing in the snapshot

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have set a stream from database that I created manually on firebase with some sample fields, when I use streamBuilder inside a stateful widget the snapshot.data return nothing/null.

```
 final CollectionReference **storeCollection** =  Firestore.instance.collection('stores'); 
                  

Stream**<List<Stores>>** get **stores** {
         return **storeCollection.snapshots()**.map(_storeListFromSnapshot);
```

Then after I used a StreamBuilder to get snapshot.data but it returns null

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return **StreamBuilder**<Object>(
        stream: DatabaseService().**stores**,
        builder: (context, **snapshot**) {
          **List<Stores> stores** = **snapshot.data** ?? []; //returns null on this line
```

I was able to update data to firebase with storeCollection.document(uid).setData()

Answer (score 0):

Usually an `AsyncSnapshot` is received at the beginning of the listening to signal that the subscription is active and it's waiting for something and it does not contain data.

You can find more checking out the docs about the [ConnectionState](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ConnectionState-class.html) enum which denotes the state of an [AsyncSnapshot](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AsyncSnapshot-class.html).

That said, the most basic thing you can do with the `builder` of your `StreamBuilder` is this:

```
builder: (context, snapshot){
  if (snapshot.hasData){
    List<Stores> stores = snapshot.data;
    //the rest of your logic on stores
  }else{ //nothing yet, we're waiting for the event, show a loader or whatever
   return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
  }
}
```